# UWP RootScrollViewer doesnt work

Tags: c#, uwp, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I built an UWP-Application with a some Views and a MainPage with a "Hamburgerlayout"

Now I have the problem, if I click in a Textbox, the virtual Keyboard will open and the application will compressed on the remaining screen... 
I tried a Scrollviewer in the MainPage and in the other pages, but without any solution...

[image]

So i built a new application, without any viewmodel etc., only two pages and tried it again.. and now if I click in the textbox, the virutal keyboard will display and I can scroll through the whole application...

[image]

I looked if there were any diferences in the XAML-Code, but I didn't find anything.. 
Any idea..?

Comment: Please specify what kind of "Hamburgerlayout" are you using. Template10 or something else? What?

Comment: Could you share the xaml code?